# Group headings and have data below. sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Could of any of you lead me in the right direction. Hopefully some of you will be kind and not act like you're the most perfect human being going on this planet.

This is my database structure
http://snpr.cm/xx03vN.png

I would like to echo out the headings and then display the corrosponding page_title underneath it.

e.g.

**My Profile & Account**

- Something

**Something**

- The page title
- Another page title

Could anybody please help me to retrieve these results? Thank you.

Comment: Show what you've attemped so far, and we'll try to help you fix it. But we won't write this for you.

Comment: Ofcourse I know you don't write it for me, otherwise I wouldn't of said "Could of any of you lead me in the right direction." which was infact the first sentence.

Anyway I have no idea where to go so I have just a normal query powered it.

this is all I have 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row['heading'];
echo $row['page_title'];
}

Comment: Yes, but at least show you've got some basic sql/php knowledge. Not to rain all over you, but there are a LOT of absolute beginners who come here with the expectation that someone'll write them the the next version of Windows or Linux from scratch in exchange for 15pts and an upvote.

Comment: Well this is my query, $sql = "
    SELECT *
           
    FROM help_pages
    ORDER BY page_title ASC";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

And that is honestly the only php I have on the page to retrieve this data.

Comment: Would I need to do a foreach() {} function, so for each heading I would need to run a query to display it's page_title's?

Comment: @user1048466 Have you tried the foreach(){} did it work, did you get an error?  to Marc B's point this is a community of developers that are more than willing to help but not until you've tried something and are stuck with an error or undesired result.  My answer below should lead you in the right direction.  If your stuck on a piece of code that isn't working feel free to post it.

Comment: No errors! But it came out wrong! Look at the "heading"'s I have in the table. http://snpr.cm/qRhqHO.png and this is what it returned me! http://snpr.cm/yuicFg.png and that's it. This is the code I'm using
`$get_help = mysql_query("SELECT heading FROM help_pages ");
$get_help_array = mysql_fetch_array($get_help);
foreach($get_help_array as $help_header) {
echo $help_header."<br/>";
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO the would be to link to have another column in there for page_id or something that would hold the page id of the page being requested.  So in this case all three columns would have a page_id of 1 and then your select statement would select based on page_id and your php code would decipher where to place the header / page_title.  You may consider having another column of page_location_id and an order by which would hold whether it's a header, title, etc and the order by would hold where exactly to display the line since you could have multiple headers and titles.  that way your code knows exactly where to put what.  As it is now your selecting on text which could become unreliable and if you change the title you will need to ensure all change. Hope this gets you going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution.

```
<?php
/*
CREATE TABLE `pages` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  `heading` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `page_title` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `page_body` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

INSERT INTO `pages` VALUES 
(1,'My Profile & Account','Something','and the body!'),
(2,'Something','The page title','The page body'),
(3,'Something','Another page title','another page body');

*/

$pages = array();

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'myuser', 'mypass');
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT heading, page_title FROM pages');
$sth->execute();
$data = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);                                                                                                                                       

// Group all page_tiles by heading
foreach($data as $record) {
    $pages[$record['heading']][] = $record['page_title'];
}

echo '<html><head><title>Page List</title></head><body>';

foreach($pages as $heading => $titles) {
    echo '<h1>' . htmlspecialchars($heading) . '</h1><ul>';

    foreach ($titles as $title) {
            echo '<li>' . htmlspecialchars($title) . '</li>';
    }   
    echo '</ul>';
}

echo '</body></html>';
?>
```